# Rotate image in HTA

Tags: css, hta

Is there any way to rotate an image in HTA using CSS without upgrading the HTA? There are several ways of doing this with CSS3, but a non upgraded HTA works like IE7 so it doesn't support CSS3. I don't want to upgrade the HTA since upgraded HTAs ignore the `<hta:application>` tag. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this:

```
<img src="example.png" width="214" height="236" style="filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1,mirror=1)"/>
```

In the `rotation=` property, `0` rotates the image 0°, `1` rotates the image 90° clockwise, `2` rotates the image 180° and `3` rotates the image 90° counter-clockwise.

In the `mirror=` property, `0` does not invert left and right and `1` inverts left and right.

Therefore, in the example above, an image that looks like this:

[image: original image]

will end up looking like this:

[image: rotated image]

Only whole numbers are permitted. This only works on IE6 and IE7, so if you want your code to be compatible with other browsers, add code that is compatible with other browsers.